# Dealing with dependent data in a Bayesian model

Tags: correlation, bayesian, inference, posterior, independence

**Background:** Consider a series of dependent data points,
$$ y_1,y_2,y_3,\cdots,y_N.
$$
In cases where the dependence is well described by an exponentially decaying
auto-correlation function, it is natural to only consider every $n$-th data point
for an approximately independent subsample (e.g. for MCMC), where $n$ is
large compared to the characteristic correlation length.

But if the data has a
more complex dependence structure, there are many ways one can obtain an
approximately independent subsample, and not obvious how to pick one subsample over another.

**My situation:** I want to calculate the posterior distribution for a set of model parameters
$\theta$, given a number of data points,

$$
p(\theta | y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_N) \propto p(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_N|\theta) p(\theta)
$$

The evaluation of the likelihood function involves a number of terms which
grows exponentially in $N$, and it is therefore unfeasible to evaluate the
model for large dependent data sets.

I do, however, know something about the dependence structure of my data. I have
a symmetric matrix of scores which indicate the dependence between each pair of
data points $y_i, y_j$ (i.e. similar to the correlation matrix). This matrix
allows me to select subset of data points (subsamples), where each data pair have a
dependence score below a threshold.

Slightly different put, I can identify
blocks of data points which are dependent above a threshold, and then identify
an approximately independent subset by selecting one data point per block.
Assuming that $y_1, y_{42},y_{51},\cdots$ corresponds to such an independent subset,
I can factorize the likelihood function, and the posterior is easily calculated as
$$
p(\theta | y_1, y_{42}, y_{51} \cdots) \propto p(y_1|\theta) p(y_{42}|\theta)
p(y_{51} |\theta ) \cdots p(\theta)
$$

There are however, a number of ways to identify a subset.

**Question:** What is the best way to approximate the posterior, given multiple
subsets of approximately independent data, but where data points in *different*
subsets have various degrees of dependence?

It seems natural to average the posterior distribution, but I am uncertain
about the validity of such an approach. If the posterior is described by
hyper-parameters, is it reasonable to average these hyper-parameters, e.g. by making an extra layer of hyper-parameters to incorporate the averaging over different subsets of the data sample?

Or, if I only manage to sample from the posterior, is it reasonable to combine equally sized samples from the
posteriors based on different subsets of the data?

Comment: What is your "degree of dependence" exactly? (e.g. does it come from something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model)?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 By "degree of dependece" I mean that some pair of data points are more dependent than others, e.g. measured by mutual information, or simply correlation coefficients in the case of an underlying multivariate normal. The point is that you can rank the different pairs, and approximate pairs with a dependence below a threshold as independent. I think I can make up an example by a PGM, would that help?

Comment: To answer this question, it would help if you can give some more specific information on the form of your likelihood function, and why it is composed of an exponential number of terms.  It might be possible to reduce this by some decomposition, but we would need to know more to help.